# Rodando Banco Dados SQL Server HD Externo

Tags: sql, sql-server, backup

Estou iniciando a construção de uma aplicação Web utilizando SQL Server e conversei com meu cliente para disponibilizar o backup da base de dados evitando acesso a sua base de produção, pois o mesmo não possui base de homologação. Foi gerado o .bak de 10GB onde sua base descompactada chega próximo dos 50GB e não tenho espaço suficiente na minha maquina, pois tenho um SSD com apenas 250GB.

Minha duvida, a possibilidade de rodar essa base de dados direto de um HD Externo, pois apenas eu irei desenvolver aplicação?

Estou descartando a possibilidade de gerar o script com a estrutura da  base de dados, pois preciso dos dados para construção da aplicação.

Obrigado e agradeço desde já.

Comment: Você tentou usar o DB no HD externo? não deu certo, deu algum erro ou coisa do tipo?

Comment: Porque voce precisa dos dados?

Comment: Testes com lista dos dados do cliente, para relatórios, grids, paginação etc

Comment: @Bacco não tentei pois estou sem HD Externo. Procurei na net e não conseguir encontrar algo na mesma situação.

Comment: Em princípio, se for um HD conectado por USB, vai ser mais lento que o acesso a um HD conectado diretamente na máquina, mas em teoria a conexão física não é pra fazer mais nenhuma diferença no acesso aos dados além disso.

Comment: @Bacco sim. HD Conectado por USB 3.0.

Comment: @BrunoLeite, sugiro que, para desenvolvimento, trabalhe com amostra dos dados e não com todo o banco de dados.

Comment: Funciona normalmente, já testei...
O HD externo precisa estar formatado em NTFS, vc pode inclusive fazer a instalação do SQL Server no HD (não recomendo fica muito lento).

Answer (score 2):

Conforme os comentários da pergunta, vai haver um pouco de perda de performance (por causa do USB) mas nada o impede de instalar/rodar o SQL Server em um HD externo.